# need to encrypt userId and password while clicking on login button of JSP page

Tags: javascript, java, spring, jsp, encryption

Hi I am new to java script.
my requirement is . i want to encrypt username and password (using AES256) while clicking on login button of jsp page .

i already have code for AES 256 encryption  which works fine.

The only thing where i am stucking is calling javascript function onsubmit event.
and this onsubmit function calls encryptFields(formName,field).

sharing my jsp code below, any quick help really appreciate.

```
<script type="text/javascript">


function onSubmit(){
    if(validateForm()){
        $.blockUI({
                message:'<img src="<c:url value="/images/loading.gif"/>"/>',
                blockMsgClass: 'black_overlay_inner'
            });
        var fieldToEncrypt = [document.fm.userId,document.fm.password];
        encryptFields(document.fm,fieldToEncrypt);
    }

}

 window.onunload = function() {
    $.unblockUI();
}; 


</script>
```

i suspect i am making mistake in below line.

I need to take username and password from this jsp page and call encryptFields()..

Comment: Although this is not the answer to your question: why would you do this? The key used to encrypt the data must be available to your script. If it is available to your page in logged out state, it is also available to an attacker, rendering the encryption useless or downgrading it to a mere obfuscation. Very likely you would either want to use https OR asymmetric encryption (elliptic curve/rsa). Unless you have a very strong security/cryptography background stick to https.